# Assigning a pandas dataframe as a subframe of another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I started using the python module pandas but when using the following code :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,3,4,5,6], '2':[10,20,30,40,50,60],'3': [100,200,300,400,500,600]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1':[22,22], '2':[22,22], '3':[22,22]})
df1.loc[[0,1],['2','3']] = df2.loc[[0,1],['1','2']]
```

I get the following dataframe :

```
df1
     1     2      3
0  1.0  22.0    NaN
1  2.0  22.0    NaN
2  3.0  30.0  300.0
3  4.0  40.0  400.0
4  5.0  50.0  500.0
5  6.0  60.0  600.0
```

I don't understand why I don't get :

```
df1
     1     2      3
0  1.0  22.0   22.0
1  2.0  22.0   22.0
2  3.0  30.0  300.0
3  4.0  40.0  400.0
4  5.0  50.0  500.0
5  6.0  60.0  600.0
```

why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

During assignment, pandas realigns the right-hand side to match the index/columns of the left-hand side.

Since your columns are not aligned, you must convert to numpy array:

```
df1.loc[[0,1], ['2','3']] = df2.loc[[0,1], ['1','2']].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
   1   2    3
0  1  22   22
1  2  22   22
2  3  30  300
3  4  40  400
4  5  50  500
5  6  60  600
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignments occur for matching indexes and columns. You didn't assign a value to column 3, so it became Nan. For example, you can use this:

```py
df1.loc[[0,1],['2','3']] = df2.loc[[0,1],['1','2','3']]
```

Comment: This is not really correct. Assuming OP really wants to assign the columns 1 and 2 of `df2` to 2 and 3 in `df1`, your code wouldn't work. Try to use `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1':[11,11], '2':[22,22], '3':[33,33]})` to see the difference.